# What does "the one I did her to" mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning, definition

M1: What was the name of your second to last song?

M2: Toxic Evolution.

M1: It's f***ing hard, man. **That's the one I did her to.**

M1 said the last line about a girl he killed. Not sure about this line, "did" means "killed"? I know that there's "do in", but I got a different situation, right? Because of the incomprehension the last line makes very little sense for me.

Comment: To "do" someone is a slang expression which means "to kill" or "to have sex with" someone. You'll have to try to figure it from context, if possible.

Comment: Yes, it's definetly "killed", but "That's the one (the song) I killed her to" still doesn't make sense

Comment: It could make sense. Have you seen the Kubrick film *A Clockwork Orange*?   Grammatically:   "We danced to that song => That was the song we danced to".  "She exercises to disco music."

Comment: Now it really makes sense! He killed her when the song was playing. Thank you very much.

Comment: @DmitriyEsarev You have been rockin with the _Ain't Rights!_

Comment: Yeah, that's true.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To do someone can mean to kill someone.

Here, it likely means something like *This is the song that was playing while I killed her* or *I killed her [eg, in rhythm] to this song.*

> 7
>   a :  to wear out especially by physical exertion :  exhaust 
>   **b :  to attack physically :  beat; also : kill**

http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/do